# VSCode C running error, message error output with gcc

Tags: c, visual-studio-code, c99

I have installed the two extensions for running c on VScode, however when I run the program, it shows the following, what should I do to fix the error?

I am using Windows 10 (64-bit) and lanague set as Chinese

[image]

Comment: We would normally much rather you did not post screenshots of your IDE, but in this case I think it's forgivable.

Comment: You appear to have two problems.  One is that VSCode's compiler-errors window is not displaying Chinese text correctly.  The other is _probably_ that VSCode doesn't know where the `gcc` tool is installed.  (I am guessing that that is what the unreadable error message means.)

Answer (score -1):

Try compiling the file manually with:

```
gcc hello.c -o hello
./hello.exe
```